# qbfc CustomerQuery based on email address?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

From the documentation, it seems like I can only "filter" for:

•   ListID or FullName
•   Active status
•   Filtering by date and time modified
•   Matching criterion for names
•   Ranges for names

Any ideas on if I can filter for other fields as well? I.e., on email address? I would prefer not to return all the customers, and iterate through them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBooks does not support searching for fields other than what you've already listed.

Comment: If you can offer some insight on this question, would appreciate it, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096092/qbfc-custom-reporting-filter-by-custom-field

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot filter on email address. Only the fields you listed.

Comment: If you can offer some insight on this question, would appreciate it, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096092/qbfc-custom-reporting-filter-by-custom-field